# Reading HDF5 inputs in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, h5py

I'm training a neural network in TensorFlow that currently takes in PNGs as inputs. While this works fine, I'd like to move to using HDF5 format inputs for more flexibility, but I'm having issues adapting the code. In both cases, a text file contains a list of the paths to all the PNG/H5 files that are to be used as training examples, one example per line. My simplified version of the current code for PNGs that works is as follows:

```
class ImageReader(object):
    def __init__(self, image_list, coord):
        '''
          image_list: string array of training image paths.
          coord: TensorFlow queue coordinator.
        '''
        self.image_list = image_list
        self.coord = coord
        self.images = tf.convert_to_tensor(self.image_list, dtype=tf.string)
        self.queue = tf.train.slice_input_producer([self.images])
        self.image = read_images_from_disk(self.queue) 

    def dequeue(self, batch_size):
        image_batch = tf.train.batch([self.image], batch_size)
        return image_batch

def read_images_from_disk(input_queue):
    img_contents = tf.read_file(input_queue[0])
    img = tf.image.decode_png(img_contents, channels=1, dtype=tf.uint16)
    return img
```

What I would like to be able to do is to replace the `read_images_from_disk` method to handle HDF5 files, specifically something along these lines:

```
def read_images_from_disk(input_queue):
    h5_contents=h5py.File(input_queue[0],'r')
    img=h5_contents['image']
    return img
```

Obviously, this doesn't work as h5py wants a string as an input and not a Tensor, and I get the error: `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'encode'` What do I need to modify to get this working?

Comment: Hey, Is that you want to save and load images from hdf5?

Comment: My image data is already saved in hdf5 format. I want to be able to load them in for my tensorflow training.

Comment: Did you find a solution for that?

Comment: @beniroquai I did not find a good solution. I ended up using TFRecords for my inputs. However, I did come across tf.py_func which lets you pass in the contents of the tensor to any python function. So if you really need to use hdf5 inputs, that can work.